# jnlp applications are opening as xml in jboss 7 server java 7

Tags: java, jboss7.x

i have a JNLP application, when i am trying to open through IEbrowser it is opening as XML file instead of JNLP.

java 6, jboss 4.2.2 with this version my jnlp applications are working fine with ie browser, but i upgraded my java 6 to java 7 along with jboss 7.0.1, manually when directly access jnlp app's it is working fine, but when come browser side it is opening the jnlp as an xml file.(i made my jnlp as jarsigner with java7)

thanks in advance;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Appserver is delivering the JNLP with the correct mime type `application/x-java-jnlp-file` and your Browser is set up correctly to open this mime type with javaws.exe. I guess your Appserver is configured to deliver the JNLP with mime type `application/xml` which causes the browser to handle it as XML file instead of as JNLP file.

Comment: hi , i am new to jboss7 server, can you help me that where can i find the mime type in jboss 7

Comment: You can configure it e. g. in your `web.xml` file. That is the more portable way than to configure it in JBoss itself.

Comment: my jnlp application is not having web.xml and the worst part is i didn't find web.xml file in jboss 7

Comment: jnlp application was developed long back with java 6 jboss 4.2.2, now we are upgrading java and jboss (jnlp is a jar file not war file, i don't understand where can i place a web.xml in a jar file)

Comment: You cannot throw a JAR file into JBoss, you have to have a WAR or EAR that is deployed afair. In a JAR you cannot have a `web.xml` that has any effect and if you want to do the config in JBoss itself, the file is not `web.xml`. Here you have a reference as to how to configure JBoss 7 mime type mappings: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/subsystem.html